# Create an object with several associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

If I have a user and article model with an association has_many :articles and belongs_to :user, I would write **user.articles.new** to create a new article object with the correct user_id .
So my question is about a model with many belongs_to relations:

```
    class Ownership < ActiveRecord::Base
            attr_accessible :right_read, :right_create, :right_update, :right_delete

            belongs_to :element
            belongs_to :user
            belongs_to :ownership_type
    end
```

Is there a solution to create **an object Ownership with the 3 IDs completed** (element_id, user_id, ownership_type_id) ?
And is it dangerous to write this IDs in the "attr_accessible" ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `new` method accepts a hash where the keys match the attributes in the model. This should work just fine:

```
Ownership.new(:element_id => element_id, :user_id => user_id, :ownership_type_id => ownership_type_id)
```

Reference: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/new/class

Also, no, it's not dangerous to include those attributes under `attr_accessible` -- actually, that's the only way you'll be able to directly write to them using `new` or `update_attributes`.